# MySQL - Sort alphabetical with numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to sort alphabetical but with numbers, but then alphabetical again???

If I do this...

`ORDER BY name ASC`

I get this...

```
2d this 10
2d this 9
this item
```

but I want this...

```
2d this 9
2d this 10
this item
```

so far I've done this...

`ORDER BY CAST(name AS UNSIGNED) ASC`

which gives me this...

```
this item
2d this 9
2d this 10
```

so it gets the `d1 this 9` and `d1 this 10` correct, but I need `this item` at the end.

I have been keeping it this way, then when looping through the results just check for `this item`, storing it and adding it to the results after the loop is finished, but is there any way to do it all within the sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the numbers at the end of the string and use that for the first key in `order by`:

```
order by regexp_replace(name, '[0-9]*$', ''),
         length(name),
         name
```

In earlier versions of MySQL, you can remove the last numbers with a bit more pain:

```
order by (case when name regexp ' [0-9]+$'
               then left(name, length(name) - instr(reverse(name), ' '))
               else name
          end),
         length(name),
         name
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=e65767dc51d36d76cc5adf32592d33a6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Looks like I don't have regexp_replace as mysql version is 5.6 - well, don't know why, assume that's the reason, I get error ``regexp_replace does not exist``

Comment: this (earlier version of MYSQL answer) still gives me the same results as I had, it  has the d1 items ordered correctly, but keeps ``this item`` at the beginning of the list instead of the end

Answer (score 0):

For this sample data you can use the function [`substring_index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
select name
from tablename
order by substring_index(name, ' ', -1) + 0 = 0, 
         substring_index(name, ' ', -1) + 0,
         name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hN9tduyryaVDpkBdK5f7Rg/2).
Results:

```
| name       |
| ---------- |
| 2a this 9  |
| 2a this 10 |
| this item  |
```